# How to disable past dates from today in bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Unable to disable the past dates in bootstrap datetimepicker

**HTML**

```
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>Datetimepicker</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
 });
```

I also used `startDate` atrribute.But no use.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/65vaoqkw/2/)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`startDate` option use in [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html?highlight=startdate#id6)  same option not mentioned anywhere in [bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/)  doc it has `minDate` option for that

```
 $(function () {
     $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  
         minDate:new Date()
      });
 });
```

**[FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65vaoqkw/7/)**

Comment: picking a time by drill down is disabled. How to solve this ? check the fiddle example you have pointed above.

Comment: combination of previous date time is disable, you can choose future date time

Comment: Yesterday, i solved the issue. the point is new Date() will make the current HH:mm tt as sealing time. instead we should point the hours directly like 
'var date = new Date();
                var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
                var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);'

https://jsfiddle.net/65vaoqkw/7/#&togetherjs=zELfaP3wpz

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
   var date = new Date();
   var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
      minDate: today
   });
});
```

Another solution:

```
$(function () { 
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
   startDate: date
  });
});
```

Comment: How to disable all dates after today?

Comment: Just change minDate to  maxDate: today

Answer (score 5):

I have used your fiddle and change it with following code which disables all the past dates, its working perfectly.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/65vaoqkw/9/) and Code -

```
$(function () {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      minDate : moment()
   });
});
```