# Bootstrap DateTimePicker, setting minDate not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've seen answers that use either, `new Date()` or `moment()` to declare `minDate` and been marked as the answer but in my case neither worked.
E.g. [How to disable past dates from today in bootstrap datetimepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915213/how-to-disable-past-dates-from-today-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

The code is:

```js
$('.datePicker').datetimepicker({
    //format: "HH:ii P, dd M yyyy",
    //format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    //minDate: new Date(),
    //minDate: moment(),
    minuteStep: 1,
    showMeridian: true,
    todayBtn: true
});
```

Bootstrap v3.3.7 is being used and it looks like:

[image]

As you can see the dates prior to the 16th (today) aren't being disabled. Could this be due to my bootstrap version?

Comment: Well you have your `minDate` commented out, which probably doesn't help...

Comment: Yes sorry I said I have tested both out with either format too. Just putting them there to show you what code I had

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using? [`minDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) is for [eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), while [tarruda's datetimepicker](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker) uses [`startDate`](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That was it, thank you very much. If you write an answer i'll accept it as the answer

Comment: @JacksonCollins I've posted my answer, I'm assuming (from screenshot) that you are using  tarruda's datetimepicker. My personal advice is to use eonasdan-datetimepicker, since it is more stable and has a richer API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`minDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) is for [eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), while [tarruda's datetimepicker](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker) uses [`startDate`](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options):

> **Options**
>
> These are the default options for initializing the widget:
>
> ```
> $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {
>   startDate: -Infinity,      // set a minimum date
>   endDate: Infinity          // set a maximum date
> };
> ```

Comment: After 4 hours of googling and looking for a fix, this worked. Thanks, @VincenzoC !